# Can't read files from OneLake shortcut to ADLS in Microsoft Fabric

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse, microsoft-fabric

I'm doing a first pass with Microsoft Fabric and can't read files with a notebook when querying files in a OneLake shortcut to an Azure Storage account.

I have configured the shortcut using Account Key for authentication.

When attempting to read a file, I receive the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling xxx.parquet. : java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: Operation failed: "Forbidden", 403
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was my storage account was not Azure Data Lake Gen2 enabled - it was a basic Azure Storage account. Slightly confused as the "Endpoints" section on the account provided me with a `dfs` option - guess this is included regardless of the underlying configuration of the storage account.

I resolved this issue by [upgrading my storage account to enable the hierarchical namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/storage/blobs/upgrade-to-data-lake-storage-gen2-how-to?tabs=azure-portal).

Comment: Posters that take the time to come back and document their solutions: GOLD. You should be able to accept this as an answer

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid for the response - appreciate it! Making an effort to log issues and solutions as I play around with Microsoft Fabric :)